# Updating a nested object with boolean values

Tags: javascript

I have a loading object, with boolean values for each loading.  My state looks like this:

```
state: {
  loading: {
    itemA: false,
    itemB: false,
    itemC: false
  }
}
```

I want to update my state using `setLoading({ itemA: true })` but having this only update itemA while keeping itemB and itemC the same as whatever the current state is.

```
return {
  ...state,
  loading: {
    ...state.loading,
    itemA,
    itemB,
    itemC
  }
};
```

Here is the full reducer (condensed):

```
setLoading: state => ({ itemA, itemB, itemC }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: {
        ...state.loading,
        itemA,
        itemB,
        itemC
      }
    };
  }
```

Unfortunately, if I `setLoading({ itemC: true })`, A and B are now undefined.

How do I ensure they are not undefined, but rather whatever is in the state?

Please note - I have tried passing just anything and doing object assign or spreading loading.

However, to increase readability, I am wondering if I can destructure the props and not have to define each loading (I have like 12 things on this page that load separately - a dashboard).

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your whole reducer `case` please?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const state = {
  loading: {
    itemA: false,
    itemB: false,
    itemC: false
  }
}

Object.assign(state.loading, {itemA: true});

console.log(state.loading);
```

Comment: Thanks, so I had this originally, but to increase readability I destructred the params.  So, some of the params could be undefined so if i pass in the undefiend ones, that is how the state will be updated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that @scarywolfman. Object.assign is more readable IMHO, and the Object.assign solution is much more failure proof and flexible than any fixed props of an object that you could pass...

Comment: Gotcha.  Guess I'll just go ahead with that and not try to be fancy :P thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a variable, that you unfold

```
  setLoading: state => (newLoadingState) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: {
        ...state.loading,
        ...newLoadingState
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide default values in your destructure

```
const fn = state => ({
    itemA = state.loading.itemA,
    itemB = state.loading.itemB,
    itemC = state.loading.itemC
}) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: {
            ...state.loading,
            itemA,
            itemB,
            itemC
        }
    };
};
```

Now when the variables are missing, they're taken from the `state` passed in;

```
const fn2 = fn({loading: {itemA: false, itemB: false, itemC: false}});
fn2({itemB: true});
// => {loading: {itemA: false, itemB: true, itemC: false}}
```